# For all $y$, there exists an $x$ where $x\geq y$

Tags: logic, peano-axioms

For all $y$, there exists an $x$ where $x\geq y$

Is this statement true or false? If so why?

My note says it's true, but I don't really get why. Thanks!

Comment: Given $y$, choose $x=y$. We need to be in a situation where $\ge $ is *defined*.

Comment: Note that $\forall y.\ \exists x.\ x \geq y$ is true (assuming $x = y$ implies $x \geq y$), while $\exists x.\ \forall y.\ x \geq y$ is usually false (it could be true, for example, if the universe is a singleton).

Comment: @dtldarek, that was the second question i was abt to ask. Why does the order matter? ∀y. ∃x. x≥y is true, then shouldn't  ∃x. ∀y. x≥y be true as well since the moving parts r the same?

Comment: @user1486802 No, because the scope of the quantifiers changes.

Comment: @user1486802 No, because the order of quantifiers determines which variables depends on which, and that matters, especially in case of $\exists$. This is a (very big) stretch, but you might think of $\forall$ as a conjunction of the formula for all the elements of the universe. Similarly an exist quantifier behaves like a disjunction. Suppose that the universe $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$. Version $\forall\exists$ is $\bigwedge_y\bigvee_x x\geq y=\bigwedge_y \mathtt{true}=\mathtt{true}$, compare it with $\exists\forall$, that is $\bigvee_x\bigwedge_y x\geq y=\bigvee_x\mathtt{false}=\mathtt{false}$.

Comment: You mean in PA(peano arithmeticy)?$ \forall x \exists y(y = S(x)) $ is a theorem. you want a proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The setting needs to be specified. For example, we could be working with natural numbers, and $x\ge y$ might mean the ordinary $\ge$ relationship.

The sentence says that **given** any specific $y$, we can produce an $x$ such that $x\ge y$.

Imagine you are given the number $17$. Can you produce an $x$ such that $x\ge 17$? Sure, easy, pick $x=17$. There are many other choices for $x$ possible, such as $x=999$. We opted for the simplest one.

Given any other value of $y$, we could produce an $x$ such that $x\ge y$: just pick $x=y$.

Answer (score 1):

If you choose any number $y$, you can always choose a larger number, as there are infinitely many numbers, or you can always let $x$ equal the number $y$ you chose.